# compile c# project during runtime

Tags: c#, compilation, resx

I have a c# project, containing mainly resource files.
I would like to edit the files at run time and recompile the project.

is that possible if so could you point me to a tutorial or some documentation regarding compiling project on run time.

Comment: What are you interested in, the resources only or the whole project contents?

Comment: the whole project it contains multiple resource files

Comment: I ask you because in case you don't have any code files in the project, you could use [Al.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to prepare an assembly containing resources only.

Comment: Okay .. I was wrong .. evry .resx file contains a designer .cs file that is autogenerated for creation of static access classes for the resources... so i need to compile first and then link everything. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am not getting your question correctly, but you should take a look at [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145008.aspx/)